# How can I load the URL from an anchor's href value in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following code:

```js
$('.big-open').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a class="big-open" href="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg">IMAGE TEST
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="big-open" href="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf">PDF TEST
    </a>
 </li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Event</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Loading...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried several options but it doesn't seem to work to open whatever content i have as "href" (either image or video or pdf file) in the modal...

I managed to get it to open only images, but that is with a workaround, and it doesnt fix my problem with other type of hrefs.

Any ideas? In the past i was using libraries such as lightbox, fancybox, etc. and it all worked smoothly. Can bootstrap do the same or i have to go back in time?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know jquery, but you can send a ajax call and get  content of file.

Answer (score 0):

try this to call your model this will surely work.

```html
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: You aren't using a URL as the href value.

Comment: @khagesh I need the content of the modal to be dynamic. I need to open the href in the modal...

Comment: sir you can use data-id="your id" on anchor tag then using javascript and ajax you can fetch data

Answer (score 0):

I created this snippet using BS4 and your code as a base and modified it to show the source data being passed in.

SO snippet manager will not allow `iframe`s with links to third party (ie: your links) so i'm just displaying the strings, but at least you can see one way to pass data to a modal.

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $("div.modal-body p").text($(e.relatedTarget).data("ref"));

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <a class="big-open" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-ref="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg">IMAGE TEST
    </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="big-open" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-ref="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf">PDF TEST
    </a>
</li>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p src="">Loading...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no way to open the href of the elements in the modal? Or is it just the fact that the links in the example are on another domain... I managed to add a <img src="ss"> into the modal and change the src with the data-ref value, and so the image is showing in the modal. Is there any way to do the same for PDF files?